# Change name of application in startup

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, registry

I have .NET Core app, that is running in the background and added in startup

I make it via adding it in the registry, like this

```
var registryKey =
            Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);

        registryKey?.SetValue("AVSPL", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

I registry app is looked like this, it's correct

[image]

But in a startup, it looks like this

[image]

Where do I need to make edit's to have name "AVSPL"?

Comment: you mean startup folder?

Comment: I mean windows startup@viveknuna

Comment: In the `Run` registry key, you create string values that reference executables, not directories. You store a directory there. A directory cannot be executed.

Comment: Can you change this property `<RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>` and give a try

Comment: I think I cannot change it to AVSPL @viveknuna

Comment: I understood, but how I can make the name `AVSPL`, not the name of the directory in a startup? @dymanoid

Comment: Reference an `AVSPL` executable file there.

Comment: You mean to write the path to executable, or how I can refer to it? @dymanoid